Dust collector on a budget - Cyclone vs pipe in/out
I'm building a dust extractor bucket and wanting to keep it to somewhat of a budget. The question I have is whether I should opt for a cyclone or go with the in/out...
When I refer to the in/out method, this is what I'm talking about.

I'm wanting to keep the bucket outfit as compact as possible, but if the in/out method will have massive tradeoffs with regards to effectiveness vs compactness, I'd like to know.
What would be the correct option here?

Can you list any references that you used prior to asking the Q? Without them we're forced to conclude you didn't do any! I'm not sorry to keep on repeating this as it's a global rule on SE, and for good reasons..... bear in mind above all else that we're instructed not to answer bad Questions, and Qs that don't list the prior research done are defined as bad.

A conventional shop vac will have the dirt-in opening attached to the canister with a deflector inside. This directs the debris in the direction necessary to prevent it from being immediately pulled by the vacuum. Your design, should it not include a vortex, would have to have some form of deflector or you've merely changed the distribution of debris within the vacuum source and within the canister.
Consider to check out the instructables web site (link for cyclone vacuum projects) to see if any match your objective. I have a purchased cyclone canister and the performance is incredible. As an anecdote, powder coating powder is dangerously fine, akin to toner powder or copier powder. I was able to collect a bag of this product from a friend's shop. Using the unmodified shop vac, the filter was immediately blackened and great puffs of powder were visible in the exhaust.
With the cyclone unit, nothing reached the filter and nothing was visible (in bright sunlight!) in the exhaust. The cyclone unit was plastered with the stuff, but easily washed out.
You'll likely get optimum results by building a cyclone unit.
